# passing font size to user control tool tip in Winform C# project

Tags: c#, winforms, user-controls

**Question:** I have a Winform C# project that changes the tool tip text of a user control tool tip when passed from a host project. I need to pass font size as a variable, but dont know where to make the changes. I have tried a plethora of solutions online and am stuck with this implementation. Any help in this direction will be really appreciated.

**What I have so far:**

I have a C# user Control project where i have set a property to set the tool tip text to change to user specified value in my UC_ToolTipButton project, where the contents of the project are as below:

UC_ToolTipButton.cs

```
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace UC_ToolTipButton
{
    public partial class UC_ToolTipButton : UserControl
    {
        public string TT_Message
        {
            get{
                return ToolTip_Message.GetToolTip(btnTT);
            }
            set{
                ToolTip_Message.SetToolTip(btnTT, value);
            }
        }
        public UC_ToolTipButton()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

In my designer file, I have placed a button (btnTT) on which I have put a tool tip (ToolTip_Message).

When I compile this User Control Forms project, it works fine and creates a dll file.

Upon importing this file in a project TryButtonTooltip, where I have the file TryTooltipForm.cs with the following content

```
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace TryButtonToolTip
{
    public partial class TryToolTipForm : Form
    {
        public TryToolTipForm()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            uC_TTMessage.TT_Message = @"Hi";
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: The ToolTip class does not have a Font property, pretty visible when you look at the Properties window.  It does not need one, the font and size of tooltips are the same for every window in every process and determined by the user's preferred theme settings.  Never that good an idea to make your app behave intentionally different, note the OwnerDraw property if you want to do this anyway.  Also note how ToolTip adds a property to every control, named "ToolTip on ToolTip_Message".  An extension property, saves you from having to create your own UserControl.

Comment: @RezaAghaei, I need to alter my current solution to pass a FontSize parameter to get Tooltip of developer defined size.

Comment: @HansPassant, in my application, it is really needed to have a bigger font size (or I could get fired)

Comment: So if the goal is changing font of tooltip, make it owner draw.

Comment: @RezaAghaei, I have changed the property to Owner draw just now, as shown in the solution provided by Arie below. However, It seems to not be working.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set `OwnerDraw` on `ToolTip` to `true`, in `ToolTip`'s `Draw` event set the desired font, then in `Popup` event measure and set the size of your `ToolTip`, as is explained in the example [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.tooltip.ownerdraw(v=vs.110).aspx).

For example like this (untested):

```
public partial class UC_ToolTipButton : UserControl
{
    public string TT_FontFamily { get; set; }
    public float TT_FontSize { get; set; }

    public string TT_Message
    {
        get
        {
            return ToolTip_Message.GetToolTip(btnTT);
        }
        set
        {
            ToolTip_Message.SetToolTip(btnTT, value);
        }
    }
    public UC_ToolTipButton()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        TT_FontFamily = "Tahoma";
        TT_FontSize = 10;
        ToolTip_Message.OwnerDraw = true;
        ToolTip_Message.Draw += new DrawToolTipEventHandler(TT_Draw);
        ToolTip_Message.Popup += new PopupEventHandler(TT_Popup);
    }

    private void TT_Popup(object sender, PopupEventArgs e)
    {
        using (Font f = new Font(TT_FontFamily, TT_FontSize))
        {
            e.ToolTipSize = TextRenderer.MeasureText(ToolTip_Message.GetToolTip(e.AssociatedControl), f);
        }
    }
    private void TT_Draw(System.Object sender,
        System.Windows.Forms.DrawToolTipEventArgs e)
    {
            e.DrawBackground();
            e.DrawBorder();
            using (StringFormat sf = new StringFormat())
            {
                sf.Alignment = StringAlignment.Center;
                sf.LineAlignment = StringAlignment.Center;

                using (Font f = new Font(TT_FontFamily, TT_FontSize))
                {
                    e.Graphics.DrawString(e.ToolTipText, f, SystemBrushes.ActiveCaptionText, e.Bounds, sf);
                }
            }

    }
}
```

Comment: the above solution does not seem to be working for me. I will inform in comment in case I have missed some part.

Comment: You have however captured the intention of the change very well. Thank you very much.

Comment: @codefrenzy I checked it and it worked properly. Make sure you assigned event handlers to the events and set `TT_Message` and `TT_FontSize` correctly.

Comment: @Arie Thank you very much. I had set the IsBalloon property to yes and it was causing me problem with font size change. I made this change and it worked. Sincerely appologize for the confusion and thank you very much.

Comment: thank you @RezaAghaei. I might not have cross-checked all the properties in the properties window if not for your continued support